# How to get Laravel (file) cached key expiration time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, caching

Is there way to get the time left for a key to expire?
Currently, I'm using Laravel file cache driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a built-in method, no.

The code for `Store`, of which `FileStore` inherits, has this logic for checking if a cache item has expired before opening its contents.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L50-L86

If you wanted to accomplish this, you would need to copy this logic.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951880/2263631), I came up with a macro:

In `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method:

```
Cache::macro('getTTL', function (string $key): ?int {
    $fs = new class extends FileStore {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct(App::get('files'), config('cache.stores.file.path'));
        }

        public function getTTL(string $key): ?int
        {
            return $this->getPayload($key)['time'] ?? null;
        }
    };

    return $fs->getTTL($key);
});
```

Usage:

```
Cache::getTTL('key_that_exists') // 20900 (in seconds)

Cache::getTTL('key_that_does_not_exist') // null
```

**Note:** This was tested in Laravel 10.0, using PHP 8.1.

**Gist:** https://gist.github.com/Script47/a0e189eb5b3a352517ae5185510f9e17

Comment: I tried your macro but it gives error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Cache\FileStore::getTTL()" in Laravel 10.13.5 under PHP 8.2.5.